# Where in "make menuconfig" is the ANDROID Kernel Config Section

Tags: android, linux, kernel

I am rebuiliding the kernel in attempt to repurpose a few GPIO pins that are allocated to Android buttons. I am having some difficulty and the next step I want to try is confirming that no conflicting Android modules are being compiled into the kernel. My problem is that I can't find those options in make menuconfig!

Comment: Without understanding exactly what it is you are trying to do, a recursive grep of the source tree might be a useful attack on the problem.

Comment: I'm looking to remove conflicting android modules that may be compiled into a kernel I'm debugging. Is there a relationship between the structure of the kernel source tree and the structure of make menuconfig?

Comment: @MattMcCann I think Android turns this all inside-out, i.e. Android makes the kernel config that it needs.  I'm still learning this too, so please let me know if you find a solution.